# Show the Instagram post when the URL to this post is entered (Python | Tkinter)

Tags: python, tkinter, input, instagram, preview

I have created a GUI using tkinter where the user can paste an Instagram post URL.
 When the link is inserted, I want this image (i.e. the Instagram post) to be displayed next to the text field before the "Run" button is pressed (it is also be possible to create a button to show the image). Unfortunately, I have no idea how to do this.
One idea would be that I download the particular image and then display it in this GUI. However, I think it would take too long to download and display each image. 
I also want the process to happen in the background. I think when an Instagram post needs to be downloaded, a web browser is opened for that (At least if you go [by this post here](https://pencilprogrammer.com/python-tutorials/download-instagram-images/)).

I've left you a snippet of the GUI here.
Note: It's not the whole code, the different buttons are already linked with functions.

```py
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("440x105")

# Label
li = ttk.Label(root, text="Post URL")
li.grid(row=0, column=0)
li = ttk.Label(root, text="Some Input")
li.grid(row=0, column=2)
li = ttk.Label(root, text="Some list")
li.grid(row=1, column=0)
li = ttk.Label(root, text="Some Input 2")
li.grid(row=1, column=2)

# Input
url_text = StringVar()
e1 = ttk.Entry(root, textvariable=url_text)
e1.insert(0, "Instagram Post URL")
e1.grid(row=0, column=1)

# Dropdown Menu
OptionList = [
    "1",
    "2",
    "3"
]
some_list = StringVar()
e3 = ttk.OptionMenu(root, some_list, *OptionList).place(x=48, y=23.5, width=110)

some_input = StringVar()
e2 = ttk.Entry(root, textvariable=some_input)
e2.insert(0, "")
e2.grid(row=0, column=3)

some_input2 = StringVar()
e4 = ttk.Entry(root, textvariable=some_input2)
e4.insert(0, "")
e4.grid(row=1, column=3)

# Buttons
b1_text = tk.StringVar()
b1 = ttk.Button(root, textvariable=b1_text, width=12, command="run")    # "Run" is linked to another function
b1_text.set("Run")
b1.grid(row=2, column=1, pady=(15, 10))

b2 = ttk.Button(root, text="Button 2", width=12)
b2.grid(row=2, column=2, pady=(15, 10))

b3 = ttk.Button(root, text="Exit", width=12, command="exit")
b3.grid(row=2, column=3, pady=(15, 10))

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: if you have direct link to image then you can use `requests` or `urllib` to get image - and it shouldn't take long. Besides if you try to display it in web browser or in some HTML widget then it also has to download it. But you could save downloaded file and not download it again. If you have URL to page then you may need BeautifulSoup to search link in HTML. Problem can be only if image need to login and if page uses JavaScript for this because then you may need [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) to control real web browser which can run JavaScript.

Comment: to run code in background you can use `threading` or `multiprocessing`. So first create function which gets URL as argument, download image and gives path to downloaded file - without using GUI/tkinter - and later use it with GUI/tkinter and `threading` or `multiprocessing`.